# Using SUBSTRING in Grails criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there any possibility to add criteria to `GORM` criteria with `SUBSTRING()`? I created result filter for data from database, and it work perfectly. But I now want to add new criteria ( something like `"find all rows from table where 2th, 3th, and 4th letter in string equals XYZ"` )  and I expected to get all rows with this string containing it on exactly this position. Of course I have other criteria with "AND" added to this filter - it's why I don't want to use `HSQL/SQL`. Position to substring always be the 2th, 3th and 4th, and whole string size have 14 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a `like` restriction - as well as the more commonly seen `%` wildcard for any substring, `like` also has the underscore wildcard for any single character.

```
like("someProperty", "_XYZ%")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did exactly what u wrote a few hour ago, but it didn't work. Now I realize that i using two restriction on the same field and second restriction spoil all. Now when i commented second restriction its work perfectly. Now i just need solve problem with  adding second restriction, and should be great.

Comment: What should I do if I want to match 3rd, 4th and 5th character? Will it be 
like("someProperty", "__XYZ%") ???